# Gosu Queries to join two tables

Tags: gosu, guidewire

How to join below two tables using gosu ..  This is from Contact Manager (GW Training App)

1 ABContact
2 BankAccount

Below SQL can be used to  find all account hold by one particluar contact

```
select b.accountnumber from ABContact a, BankAccount b where
a.id=b.contactid and a.id='123'
```

Please write the same query in Gosu

Answer (score 2):

Query is like this

```
uses gw.api.database.Query

var account: BankAccount 
var query = Query.make(ABContact).join("ID", BankAccount, "Contact").compare(BankAccount#ID, Equals, account.ID)
```